Give advice on justifying belief in the existence of other minds
Solipsism has the fewest entities (only my mind) and therefore it is the most minimal explanation.
Does that make it more likely than the existence of other minds? Because other minds offer billions of minds.
Many entities.
Everything in the universe tends to the lowest energy level.
So, should we consider the explanations that have the least number of entities to be true?
Does explanatory power matter more?
Is the number of entities crucial or important?
What are the solutions to this problem?
Please explain.

I want to understand whether a smaller number of entities is a priority or it all depends on the situation. If it is reasonable to look for an explanation with the minimum number of entities, then solipsism should be the most rational and therefore proven, but it is not. So there is some explanation why solipsism lost. Solipsism wins in the number of entities because it offers only one entity (there is only my mind). But are there any laws of the universe that say to look for the smallest number of entities? How did IBE deal with this issue?

I want to know if quantitative simplicity is the main criterion in IBE. Are all IBE criteria equal? The argument says that the existence of other minds is simple, clear, unified, but has a large number of entities. That is, it is 3:1 in favor of the existence of other minds or what? Where exactly is the explanatory power in my criteria?

What to do with the fact that solipsism offers a smaller number of entities? I'm stuck here.

Have you seen the movie I Robot (2004)? Spoiler alert! The character Sonny is a robot who speaks and acts as if he has the mind of a human being! When we watch a movie there is a thing called suspension of disbelief. I don't know why philosophers are so concerned about some states of belief and disbelief. We automatically recognize the other mind(s) and we can develop faith or doubt as to whether the other mind(s) in fact exist! All this occurs in the mind! Efforts to justify belief or disbelief occur in the mind! Other minds arise in the mind as the product of an unconscious process.

The number of entities is generally an irrelevance, and you seem to be confusing yourself because  you think otherwise. By your logic, a theory that asserts a block of iron, say, is a seamless blob, is better than one that considers the bar to be made of countless particles. Having separate entities is a problem if every one of them requires a separate justification. If a single assumption accounts for all the entities, there is generally not a problem. In your argument for solipsism, all of the other brains apart from yours are still 'entities' under solipsism, since they have to be accounted for in some way. It is nonsense to say that solipsism posits only one 'entity'. `

Why do you say "in general"? Solipsism suggests that not all people exist at the same time, but only those with whom I interact. And here mind and body are counted as separate entities. One mind and, for example, 5 bodies has fewer entities than 5 minds and 5 bodies. Explain it.

I've already told you- the number of entities is an irrelevance unless you have a reason to claim otherwise. That is why you are confused and are continually asking the same question. Rid your mind of the entities nonsense.

That is, there are IBE criteria, among which there is a number of entities. The existence of other minds is simple, clear, unified, and solipsism has fewer entities. So 3:1 in favor of other minds? Does it work any other way?

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101256/how-does-the-ibe-arrive-at-the-best-explanation here it is said that simplicity is not the only criterion, but I do not understand what simplicity is meant: quantitative or explanatory. Also, where does unification apply? To simplicity or to some other criterion?

Why are you stubbornly ignoring what I have told you? The number of entities is irrelevant unless you have a good reason to assume otherwise.

"The number of entities is irrelevant unless you have a good reason to assume otherwise" - please explain this. Tell me in which cases we should start counting the number of entities?In what cases does the number of entities matter?

The number of entities matters where you have to make separate, independent assumptions to justify the existence of each one.

That is, you need to look for the best explanation? Here are the criteria used by IBE: depth, comprehensiveness, simplicity and unifying power; Depth, Power, Falsifiability, Modesty, Simplicity, Conservativeness. That is, solipsism wins only in one criterion, but loses in all other criteria. We need to compare the explanations and see which explanation wins? Explain how it works.

I'm wasting my time talking to you because you seem not to be taking in a word I say. You are still claiming that solipsism 'wins on simplicity' despite the fact that I have tried to tell you that claim is pure nonsense.

Solipsism offers only one entity, while the existence of other minds offers billions of entities. One less than billions. So when compared, who wins in the criterion of the number of entities?

You are wrong to assume solipsism requires an explanation for only one 'entity'. If you assume yours is the only 'real' mind, you still have to account for all the consequences of the other billions of unreal minds. How do you account for the existence of my answers, for example?

since we cannot see all 8 billion people at once, we need some justification to believe that there really are 8 billion conscious people in the world. Solipsism suggests that there are only those people with whom we interact (that is, there is only what you interact with). This is the problem. Ontologically, it is simpler. But the existence of other minds has a much better explanatory power.

Solipsism is unconvincing because solipsism claims a special status for you for no reason: the behavior of other people is created by your mind for you to see; The whole world is created by your mind so that you can see it. If we assume that the universe is as we see and feel it: objective, permanent, independent, etc. then all the people around are real and exist independently of your mind.

And then everything is simple. Other people are similar to us anatomically and have behaviors similar to ours. The best explanation is that other people have minds because it is a unified, simple and understandable explanation that is economical and does not violate the principle of uniformity, symmetry and analogy.

The only problem is that I do not know what is more important: the number of entities and special status or the number of explanations, unification, the principle of uniformity and symmetry? How to determine which criteria are more important?

I have tried to tell you, and you are not listening. The number of entities, per se, is utterly meaningless, and has no bearing on the plausibility of an argument. What counts is the cumulative probability of having n separate assumptions. Every assumption has a probability, and the overall probability of the set of assumptions is the product of their individual probabilities (assuming they are independent). So for every assumption you add, you decrease the overall probability. You can therefore make an argument more plausible by eliminating unnecessary assumptions...

...however, the probabilities of the assumptions have to be taken into account, not just the number of them. An argument with ten plausible assumptions is still preferable to an argument with one assumption if the probability of that one assumption is lower than the collective probability of the ten.

That seems to be what you are failing to understand. You cannot decide whether an argument with n assumptions is better or worse than an argument with m assumptions purely on the basis of whether n is larger or smaller than m, so the question you are asking is pointless.

ok, then please explain why the existence of other minds is the best explanation for other people's behavior. I want to see how IBE rejects solipsism.

"What counts is the cumulative probability of having n separate assumptions. " - explain this please

I already did, three comments ago! Make an effort to read and digest!

Why is the probability of the existence of other minds higher than the probability of solipsism?
